# Codeigniter 404 error is shown

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am following the tutorial-Static pages, from codeigniter website.

1. I extracted the codeignitor zip into my local server.
2. Edited the line

   ```
   $config['base_url']='http://localhost/';
   ```

in application /config/config.php

3. Created the file: application/controllers/pages.php to have following contents:

   ```
   <?php

   class Pages extends CI_Controller {

   public function view($page = 'home')
   {
       if ( ! file_exists('/var/www/application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
   {
       // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
       show_404();
   }

   $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

   $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
   $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
   $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
   }
   }
   ```
4. Created the file: application/views/templates/header.php with some HTML content.
5. Created the file: application/views/templates/footer.php with some HTML content.

Now, when I go to

```
  localhost/index.php/pages/view/about
```

I expect the 'about' page, but 404 error is shown.

Why is that?

Comment: try to use this code file_exists('/var/www/application/views/pages/about.php')

Comment: and to see if it work or not

Comment: file_exists('/var/www/application/views/pages/about.php') is working thanks. But not file_exists('/var/www/application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try following

```
if (file_exists(APPPATH."views/pages/". $page. ".php")) {

   $this->load->view("pages/". $page);

}
```

`APPPATH` = well self explanatory

Comment: Still the problem is with file_exists(APPPATH."views/pages/". $page. ".php" or  file_exists('/var/www/application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php') or file_exists('application/views/pages'.$page.'.php') I guess

Comment: Regarding your code, no output displayed. (as you didnt use ! infront of file_exists function).

Comment: If I use ! infront of file_exists function (in your code), the output error is 404 file not found.

Comment: well, your file is missing, is in wrong case, please try this if(true) {//simple if else concept} else {}... try var_dump() php function for debugging...

Comment: But I see this working: file_exists('/var/www/application/views/pages/about.php'), but not this: file_exists('/var/www/application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')

Comment: Its working now. Don't know how. Thanks for the info about var_dump() anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here-

```
if ( ! file_exists('/var/www/application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

You should also mention the name of your codeigniter folder as well!

Comment: What is codeignitor folder? Actually, that path dont exist, so I rewrite as '/var/www/application/views/'.$page.'.php' but the new error is "An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: pages/about.php"

Answer (score 0):

Some webservers expect a question mark, like so:

```
localhost/index.php?/pages/view/about
```

Can you test this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
$config['base_url']='http://localhost/';
```

Try

```
$config['base_url']='http://localhost/project_name/';
```

Comment: Please stop and learn how to format the code you're posting in your answers. Looking around at the other questions and answers should indicate to you that we expect you to learn how to format your posts correctly.